# wait for x time or flag is true using pthread in C

Tags: c, pthreads

How can I wait for a given time x or a char y is set to 1.
For example I want to implement following method

```
void wait(int x, char *y){

}
```

How can I implement this so calling this method wait for x time or until y is not 0. whichever happens first.

thanks in advance

Comment: It would probably be better to use a condition variable and `pthread_cond_timedwait(3)` and explicitly tell the thread when `y` is ready using `pthread_cond_signal(3)`.

Comment: What kind of data or "event" is it that you're waiting for by the way? There might be other approaches too.

Comment: thanks for the reply. 

It sounds like I'd have to implement signal code in another function which changes the y variable. 

y is the key pressed by the user which is managed by another thread.

Comment: Looking into `select(2)` (`poll(2)` and `epoll(7)` are similar -- the latter is Linux-specific) might be worthwhile too. It's the usual way to wait for events (e.g., data being available) on a set of file descriptors (e.g., *stdin*).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a condition variable to do this.  The wait function would do:

```
void wait(int x, char *y)
{
    struct timespec deadline;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &deadline);
    deadline.tv_sec += x;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&y_lock);
    while (*y == 0) {
        if (pthread_cond_timedwait(&y_cond, &y_lock, &deadline) == ETIMEDOUT)
            break;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&y_lock);
}
```

Then the code elsewhere that sets `*y` to 0 would use `pthread_cond_signal()`:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&y_lock);
*y = 0;
pthread_cond_signal(&y_cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&y_lock);
```